# Starting Development for Google Chrome....Getting Started Issues!

Tags: visual-c++, webkit, google-chrome

Our organization has decided that my project will be developed for internal use with the Google Chrome browser.  So yesterday I started looking around the internet for just how I would go about doing that.

I found the WebKit.org development tool and have been trying to install it using the instructions found here:
http://webkit.org/building/tools.html

I am installing on a Windows machine that does not have Visual Studio 2005, so following the directions I downloaded Visual C++ Express 2005.  Now I am at:

*Install the Windows Server 2003 R2 Platform SDK, then follow steps 2 and 3 of “How to: Use Visual C++ Express Edition with the Microsoft Platform SDK.”*

Except I can't follow steps 2 and 3 because when I go to try and run the program all I have in the menu is:
Start -> Programs -> Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt

which opens a command prompt.

Can anyone tell me what I've done incorrectly?

Additionally, do you HAVE to develop in WebKit?  Or is that just the best way to work with the Chrome engine?

Thanks!
Leslie

Comment: What is the project you're working on? Is it a web application (like GMail), a Chrome plugin (http://www.chromeplugins.org/) or a standalone application which must display HTML content? Each has a completely different development path.

Comment: I don't know if it would be classified as a web application or a standalone application.  It's currently a desktop application that is being converted to a browser based application.  Up until yesterday we had been developing for IE, now we've decided that Chrome will be the standard browser for our organization.

It's a fairly complex system - it's a Jury Management System that tracks summonses, jury trials, jurors on the trials, hours worked and payments.

Thanks!

Comment: How does IE currently connect to your application? If the connection to your backend is completely HTTP, it doesn't matter what browser you use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to 'build chrome'

If you need anything special, the Chrome Extension framework is pretty awesome: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html

But I imagine if you are moving from IE to Chrome, as a client for a webapp, things should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Leslie,

I found this [Google I/O talk](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/DevelopingExtensionsGoogleChrome.html) to be useful as an intro.

Answer (score 0):

step 2 and 3 are on Microsoft's web site referred in the building instructions. The steps describes steps you need to do after opening Visual C++. If you have only the command prompt in the Visual Studio start menu folder, reinstall your Visual C++ Express edition.

I don't think writing your own webkit-based browser satisfies your decision to use the Google Chrome browser. By the way. From your limited description of your requirement I don't see why it cannot be a B/S application. If you have too many C++ code to port to web, you can try host [Google Chorme Frame as an ActiveX](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/5473a4625ee3bd50/f57ce6544f59f25a?#f57ce6544f59f25a). I am not sure if this is the best approach for you, since it does not have any API documentation for developers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to reinstall

I don't know what you mean a 'B/S application'.  
It's currently written in Delphi, not C++.  

The decision was made that Chrome will be the default browser for  the court.  We currently have several applications that require the use of IE7.  The Jury application has been scheduled to be converted to a web application for most of last year (we were working on the conversion when I was injured and my team dropped the ball on development when I was out).  

Since we have now decided to use Chrome as the default browser I was looking into it's development tools.

Comment: B/S stands for browser/server， which is a special case of client/server architecture where the client is a web browser.

if your client mandate using of Chrome as the client interface, you have no choice but to port your Delphi code to a web application. Could be a major rewrite if your business layer is not web-aware, or your code is not separated into multiple tiers.

Comment: So the reinstall didn't work...still only had the command prompt.  I have been able to get a copy of Visual Studio 2005 so I'm going to install that and follow those instructions.  Maybe I can get it to work.
Sounds like B/S is where we will want to go.  We are definitely going to have to re-write the application, which isn't a problem.  I'm just trying to figure out the best way to develop for Chrome.
Hopefully I'll be successful getting the webkit installed with the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a browser based app could mean:

1. You run code (perhaps in .Net, Java, Ruby, PHP, Python, etc...) on a server with potentially Javascript, flash, etc... running in the browser.  The browser communicates with the server through HTTP requests.  If that is the case you certainly don't need to worry about installing webkit.
2. It could mean writing a Chrome extension which would again likely mean running .Net, Java, Ruby, Python, PHP, or some other language of your choice on the server and Javascript in the Chrome extension.  Again in this case there is no need to install webkit.
3. It's possible it could mean writing an app based on webkit, but that would be replacing your old desktop app with another desktop app which doesn't seem likely.  With this solution, you are no longer running Chrome, but your own custom made browser.  Not to mention this seems like overkill for a jury management system.

I would guess you want to do option 1.  That is typically what people mean by a browser based app.  It would be a much better use of your time to read a book on web development than to fool around with webkit.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the executable file to launch Visual Studio Express in this folder: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8.0\Common7\IDE\"